# A line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uniquely determined by two points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm preparing Euclidean geometry for the exam and in my notes I come across the exercise :" **A line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uniquely determined by two points.**"

Is this like a claim that needs to be proven or more like a question of whether it is true?
I wouldn't say it's a claim because I don't think it's true. A line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined with one point and a vector, or it can also be defined as the intersection of two planes, right?
I'm really new to all this and I don't really understand. Could someone please clarify this for me.
How is a line uniquely determined in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Given two points $p$ and $q$, there is a unique line that passes through $p$ and $q$. The claim is true in this sense.

Comment: If you take one of the points and the vector from that point to the other point, does that meet your definition?

Comment: By two _distinct_ points.

Comment: It doesn't mean, "the only way to determine a line is by two points".

Comment: @Aruralreader - it is not necessary to add "distinct" by standard mathematical usage. If the two points were not distinct, they would be one point, not two. If the statement had identified the points by labels, such as "let $a, b$ be two points", then adding "distinct" is needed to clarify that "two" is the number of actual points, not labels.